# Certificate not sent in CertificateRequest when running from Tomcat but sent when running from main class

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, jersey-client, mutual-authentication

We have a destination web application running a restful web service. This application runs in Tomcat 8.5 and has TLS enabled with 2-way authentication.

Our application is also a web application running on Tomcat 9.

The destination endpoint I am invoking for one of the funcationlaties is an SSE endpoint. To consume this endpoint, I am using the Jersey client.

Below is the code snippet which makes the call:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  SSLContext sslContext = createSslContext();

  Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();

  try
  {
    callEndpoint(client);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    if (client != null)
    {
      client.close();
    }
  }
}

private static SSLContext createSslContext()
{
  SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
     .trustStoreFile("C:\\truststore")
     .trustStorePassword(password)
     .keyStoreFile("C:\\keystore")
     .keyStoreType("JKS")
     .keyStorePassword(password)
     .keyPassword(password);

  SSLContext sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
  return sslContext;
}

private static void callEndpoint(Client client)
{  
  client.register(new ClientRequestFilter()
  {
      public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
      {
          requestContext.getHeaders().add("auditUser", "user");
          requestContext.getHeaders().add("auditClientIp", "hostname);
      }
  });

  WebTarget target = client.target(url);

  EventInput eventInput = target.request().header("Content-Type", "application/fhir").get(EventInput.class);

  while (!eventInput.isClosed())
  {
    eventInput.setChunkType(MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE);
    InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();

    if (inboundEvent != null)
    {
      System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName() + "; " + inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works when running through a standalone, main class.

However, when the same runs from within the web application, the call fails with `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate`

On comparing the SSL debug logs in both cases, I noticed that in the case of the web application, the application does not send any certificate in the Certificate request.

Below is the excerpt from both logs:

**Main Class:**

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE>
<CN=MYHOSTNAME>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 179
...
...
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
matching alias: le-c979850e-fd8d-4a61-87da-8c25eef1dea1
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
...
```

**Web Application:**

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE>
<CN=MYHOSTNAME>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 179
...
...
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
```

The keystore and truststore used in both cases point to the same files. Is Tomcat interfering in anyway causing the client certificate to be not sent?

**NOTE:** The paths for the keystore and truststore used by the Jersey client is read through configuration and is not the one configured for Tomcat.

Is it mandatory for all SSL calls from within a Tomcat application to use the one configured for Tomcat? Can a different keystore be not used? If not, is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Earlier in the debuglog, before the hello exchange, it should show the keymanager being initialized; through j10 there should be a line like `found key for : $alias` followed by the cert chain like `chain [0] = ... maybe 10-30 lines ... chain [1] = ... ditto ... etc` Is that present and contain the correct cert(s)?

Comment: Clearly Tomcat isn't using that keystore.

Comment: The keystore and truststore used are not the same as the ones used for Tomcat. Clarified the same in the question.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : the lines you mentioned are present and contains the correct information

Answer (score 0):

It is 2 way SSL, perhaps client's(Tomcat 9) public key(`x.509`) not in Tomcat 8.5 application truststore. To verify, run [SSLPoke](https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029) program at Tomcat 8.5 server and set  application truststore path.

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=</path/to/jks> SSLPoke <IP> <PORT>
```

Ensure Tomcat 9 public key installed inside Tomcat 8.5 truststore.

Comment: Our application is not utilizing the keystore configured for the parent Tomcat. It is a different one. Sorry for the confusion, I will update the same in the question.